# Three or four-wire plugs for electronic lab use

Tags: connector, i2c

I'm doing experiments with various sensors and I'd like to build peripherals with three or four pin plugs. This is DC power (3 or maybe 5 volts) and either an analog signal or low-speed I2C. I'd like to be able to have up to 30cm or so of wiring on each side of a plug. I'm fine with building my own cables, but I haven't done it before and I'd like to standardize on something so I don't have to do it too often.

Any suggestions? I see that Sparkfun and Adafruit use 1mm and 2mm JST connectors on their sensor boards but they don't seem to have a way to plug two cables together; the connectors are on the boards.

Edit: the terminology seems to be "wire-to-wire connector" to distinguish from a "wire-to-board connector."

Comment: Consider Cat 5 STP pre-made

Comment: Comment on terminology: Headers are on the boards. Plugs are on the cables.

Comment: If you like to use JST , consider STP wire for shielded signals http://www.mattmillman.com/info/crimpconnectors/common-jst-connector-types/

Comment: Or buy the cables https://www.adafruit.com/product/4045

Comment: JST also makes a variety of "wire-to-wire" connectors if you don't want to use the PH series connectors used by Sparkfun and Adafruit. https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/productguide_e.php?category_id=11  They are not as ubiquitous, though. I think somebody makes "headers" for jst ph series plugs that can actually go on a wire. But it is not JST and they are kind of weird looking.

Comment: If you search for "Grove connector" you'll find 4-pin connectors and cables that are somewhat standardized. Here is one kit: https://www.mouser.com/new/seeed-studio/seeed-studio-grove/

Comment: I2C might be low speed but due to open-drain drivers it can easily gather crosstalk from neighbouring signals. Please be aware that just connecting wires together may not work. It needs planning even with twisted pair wires how to do it the right way. Done correctly it can run a few meters without doing any out of ordinary measures such as differential long range I2C buffers.

Comment: Grove connectors seem to be wire-to-board connectors?

Answer (score 0):

(This is a tentative answer; just talking about one possible solution.)

There are many connector types out there, but it seems that JST-SM connectors are pretty common? I see that Adafruit sells cables with 4-pin plugs: https://www.adafruit.com/product/578

Also, they seem quite common on Amazon. Annoyingly they tend to be sold in bundles with 15cm wires attached and sometimes I need a bit longer.

I guess I should buy some and see if it's worth getting a crimping tool.